# Xcode debug hint

Tags: ios, xcode

When the app crashed, I moved the mouse pointer over the audioObject where the little popup showed up.  Does the >nil in the popup tell me that audioObject is nil?  Because it would not make any sense if it was.
[image]

Comment: Yes that what its saying... its Nil...

Comment: You may want to put a breakpoint before it, then run the application. Sometimes moving the breakpoint around will cause wierd results.

Comment: To be 100% sure `NSLog()` everything. The debugger used to be / still is (?) quite buggy :(